# Bootstrap 5 button border color via css

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

i try to make a page to control my amp via various js libs.

1.) Can you tell how do i can change the blue border of a selected bootstrap 5 button? (to a lighter green instead of blue, i want to avoid scss to make it as simply as possible)

**Showcase:**
https://schoko11.github.io/KEKO-WEB/#

**Repo(sorry for the mess, it is not the newest version but the problems are visible):** https://github.com/schoko11/KEKO-WEB

2.)When using this on a large screen you can see a white background on the bottom because the grey background does not stretch down the whole viewport height.... -> i set body to

> height: 100vh;

Thanks!

Comment: That blue border really is `box-shadow` on `:focus` pseudo class. From the [document on this page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/), it seems there is no way to modify without CSS or Sass (Scss). For 2.) set your class `allCont` to have full height.

Comment: thanks @vee, how can i fix 1.) with css(i just want to avoid sass), and how to do 2.) exactly ? thank you?

Comment: Use browser inspector (F12) and inspect that element about CSS class they use. Copy those CSS and override in yours. The answer is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) From the [document on this page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/buttons/), you can change blue border only via CSS or Sass (Scss). The blue border actually is `box-shadow` on `:focus` and/or `:active` pseudo class.

2.) You have to set full height for `allcont` class.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <div class="allCont">
            <div class="wrapper-for-test">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
                    A Button
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}


.allCont {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, .5); /* for test only */
    height: 100%;
}

.btn-check:focus + .btn-primary, 
.btn-primary:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
.btn-check:active + .btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-check:checked + .btn-primary:focus, 
.btn-primary.active:focus, 
.btn-primary:active:focus, 
.show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 .25rem rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}

/* for test only */
.wrapper-for-test {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

[See it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/Lv6wr80y/)

Comment: Thanks i mark that as answered, i need to fiddle it into my project. Thank you very much!